# What happened to The Enchantress of Numbers?

Tags: biopic

Back in 2010, there were some [rumors](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni2132437/) that Zooey Deschanel would play Ada Lovelace in a movie called "The Enchantress of Numbers." [Apparently](http://www.themarysue.com/zooey-deschanel-not-ada-lovelace/) she actually wasn't going to play her, but what ever happened to the movie? Did it ever exist in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this was one of those movies that just *vanished*. Any googling immediate turns up a plethora of pages mostly within the same week period, all with the same details, and nothing else.

The movie *was* going to star *Zooey Deschanel* as Ada Lovelace. It *was* going to be directed by *Bruce Beresford*. (see [here](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Zooey-Deschanel-To-Play-Enchantress-Of-Numbers-Ada-Lovelace-18148.html) or [here](http://news.moviefone.com/2010/04/21/zooey-deschanel-is-the-enchantress-of-numbers/)). It was also going to star *Billy Crudup* as her husband, William King, and *Toby Jones* as Charles Babbage (see [here](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=27628)).

The most information I can find, from the final link above, is:

> Beresford plans to shoot the period drama, which would chronicle the
>   time they spent working together, in the autumn [of 2010].

However, as you comment, Zooey pulled out of the project. There doesn't seem to be any information after that. I can only speculate that the film simply *fell through* (possibly due to not finding a good lead, or a dislike of the script) and all parties moved on to other things.

Comment: *sigh* They ***always*** drop all the good ideas!